# How to create dropdownlist on Excel 2003

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-2003, excel-interop

I'm creating Excel files using `AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Excel.Application")`.

I'm using these lines of codes to create a dropdown list:

```
mySheet.Range("A1").Validation.Add(Type:=Interop.Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateList, _
        AlertStyle:=Interop.Excel.XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop, _
        [Operator]:=Interop.Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween,
                                            Formula1:="=List!$C$3:$C$903")
```

The formula (Formula1:="=List!$C$3:$C$903") returns 900 rows

In Excel 2010 it works perfectly, however, in Excel 2003 no dropdownlist are created on the cell

Any alternative ways?

Comment: Does the end of your code `Formula1:="=List!$C$3:$C$` is a typo or does the list have no end? What do you see on your workbook when you look at the validation on your cell >> please precise `it's not working`

Comment: I have updated my question, I'm using vb.net, no dropdownlist are created, just a empty cell

Comment: what if you put an end to the formula? something like: `Formula1:="=List!$C$3:$C$"`. I don't think it would work on 2003 if you don't put an end to your formula.

Comment: OK, I just found out that I cannot use references to other worksheets or workbooks for data validation with Excel 2003. That's why this formula: Formula1:="=List!$C$3:$C$903" just won't work. "List" is the name of the other Sheet from my Workbook. So right now I'm not sure what formula to write.. =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create a dropdown list from another sheet in Excel, you have to create a [named range](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/named.htm) and then declare the named range in the Validation formula.

See [this tutorial](http://www.contextures.com/xldataval05.html) on how to do it from scratch.