# dropdown value limit in Excel when created from vb.net throws error when values are more than 255 characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, excel, spreadsheetgear

I am working on dynamic creation of dropdown using VB.Net and SpreadsheetGear dll and populate it with values as below

worksheet.Range(Range).Validation.Add(ValidationType.List, ValidationAlertStyle.Stop,
                                                          ValidationOperator.Between, flatList, "")
I am using validation.add to create the dropdown

here flatList is the comma seperated string dropdown values.

It is working FINE with flatlist characters less than 255 characters, but if it is more than 255 it throws below ERROR message

```
 **Data Validation lists are limited to 255 characters.**
```

Kindly Help
Ramesh.T.

Comment: I think it is an Excel limitation, you can use a named range instead and put the valid data in that range.

Comment: I want to add this dropdown only through VB.Net code. May i know if Named range is possible through vb.net, If so can you please help me in providing reference link URL.

Comment: [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805207/how-to-create-dropdownlist-on-excel-2003) might help.